# Can't set ultawide resolution

Tags: linux, xrandr, gpu, amd, solus

I have a *21:9 monitor*. In every single linux distro `2560x1080`resolution doesn't work for me. Why? My GPU is really old. I fixed it in `antergos(arch-based distro!)` by installing a package called `linux49` from manjaro repository and by setting `radeon.hdmimhz=372` in kernel options. After that I was able to select the *2560x1080* resolution. Solus isn't arch-based so maybe someone has an idea how can I fix my issue? I know for sure that adding a custom resolution in `xrandr` resizes the screen, but it's very blurry and unusable.

## GPU: Radeon HD 6870

Comment: change the distro

Comment: not so funny after hearing it for the 100th time when I'm not using arch

Comment: The obvious way is to find out whatever was in the linux49 package, esp. wrt. radeon drivers, write down the version and/or patches they used to built these, and do the same on Solus, either by looking through the repositories, or by compiling it yourself. Yes, this is a lot of work, and you need to know how to compile stuff yourself. But it's better than guessing, installing random stuff and crossing fingers, or complaining it doesn't work. On Linux you *can* do stuff like this yourself.

Comment: @DZDomi We usually don't recommend anyone to change the distribution in here. Stop that, please.

Comment: some people dont have a sense of humor ;)

Answer (score 0):

## Radeon HD 6870 specification

> Max Resolution Details DVI: 2560 x 1600 / DisplayPort: 2560 x 1600 / HDMI: 1920 x 1080 / VGA: 2048 x 1536

## Conclusion

Neither VGA, nor HDMI < version 2.0 are not capable of delivering such a resolution.

You need to connect through DisplayPort in order to do that.

Comment: So DVI-HDMI should work?

Comment: No. I said your version of HDMI output  is limited to 1080p.